# How to display ActionBarSherlock menu items on the top and bottom bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, contextmenu, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I am currently trying to implement "action mode" with ActionBar Sherlock. When the "action mode" launches, I would like to have some of the menu items (2 of them) displayed on the top action bar and some others (5 items) on the bottom actionbar.

I have added this configuration to my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity
   android:name=".MyActivity"
   android:label="@string/myActivity"
   android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
```

and this is my oncreateActionMode :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_1))
          .setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_1))
          .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

      menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_2))
          .setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_2))
          .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

      menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_3))
          .setIcon(
              getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_3))
          .setShowAsAction(
              MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                  | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

      menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_4))
          .setIcon(
              getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_4))
          .setShowAsAction(
              MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                  | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

      menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_5))
          .setIcon(
              getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_5))
          .setShowAsAction(
              MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                  | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

      menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_6))
          .setIcon(
              getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_6))
          .setShowAsAction(
              MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                  | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

      menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_7))
          .setIcon(
              getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_7))
          .setShowAsAction(
              MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                  | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

      return true;
    }
```

With this configuration, I have the top and bottom action bar but **all my menu items** are displayed on the bottom action bar. The problem is then I want to have the two first menu items to be on the top action bar and the remaining 5 on the bottom action bar. Is it possible ?

Do you guys have some idea of how I should proceed ?

thanks a lot ...

Comment: You can't. Menus go in one place or the other.

Comment: But in the native gmail app they have menu items in both top and bottom. I don't know how. :(